# Phalcon MVC model Exception

Tags: php, autoload, phalcon, executequery

I'm trying to create an API with Phalcon for the first time.
I have been followed the tutorial "http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html", but encountered a problem.
I've been created a new project with all the settings, and inside I got:

1. a `"models"` folder with `"photos.php"` file
2. a `"index.php"` with connection to my DB and function to retrieve information from "photos" table

The problem is that when I'm trying to activate the function through the browser i get an Error:

> "Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception: Model 'photos' could not be loaded inC:\wamp\www\Test\index.php on line 77".

```
$photos = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql); // line 77
```

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's one of three problems:

1 - Your class name in photos.php is not photos.

2 - You have mis-referenced the photos model in your PHQL query.

3 - You have not registered the directory where your models are stored. To do this, add

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    '/path/to/models'
))->register();
```

after

```
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
```

but before

```
$app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create project structure using Phalcon developer tool, the `config.ini` might need an update like this:

```
from:
modelsDir      = /models/

to:
modelsDir      = **..**/models/
```

Answer (score 0):

i just faced same issue, got it solved by add require with model path right after `$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();` and

```
before $app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro($di);
```

like suggested by brian